# WPF DataGrid ContextMenu data transfer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

Good day to everyone! I'm new into WPF and .NET and trying to make serious application in it. In part, that I can't figure how to make right, I have **`Grid`** that contains **`TabControl`** with some tabs, on every tab I have **`DataGrid`** with data from MySQL. This part is not so difficult, but now I need to make some filter, that enables/disables some columns by user choice. For that I use **`ContextMenu`** that on calls on click new window with list of column names. On every tab. So I made universal **`Filter_Window`**. I figured how to get this names, but can't get the **`DataGrid`**, that calls for **`Filter_Window`**. I tried **`VisualTreeHelper`**, but **`ContextMenu`** have it's own VisualTree and it's gave me nothing. **`DataContext`** gave nothing eather.
 Just don't want to make Click for every Tab separately, it's not right, but it's most obvious solution. Just need the way to transfer **`DataGrid`** to **`Filter_Window`**.
Sorry for my language, if I name things bad. If code samples needed to clarify what I written - say and I'll post some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did found more suitable for me answer, but forgot to post it here. Done with Command and CommandParameter. What I did in XAML in MainWindow:

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
  <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <MenuItem x:Name ="AktFilter" Header="_Фильтры..." Command="{StaticResource ResourceKey=FilterCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}"/>
  </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

and added new Command into project:

```
class FilterCommand : ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            FilterWindow newW = new FilterWindow();
            newW.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            newW._sender = parameter as DataGrid;
            newW.ShowDialog();//можно через условие нажатия на ок попробовать запилить обработку сохранения или !!!!! смену состояния строк
            if (newW.DialogResult == true)
            {
                DataGrid dg = parameter as DataGrid;
                Filters filterList = (Filters)newW.FilterDG.ItemsSource;
                for (int i = 0; i < dg.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (filterList[i].Visible)
                    {
                        dg.Columns[i].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dg.Columns[i].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                    //тут еще засунуть фильтры!!!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code generates DataGrid from column names and checkboxes, changes only applied while running program, save of Visibility is not done yet...
Was too lazy, got back to program only now.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with `boolean` properties of all columns of your `DataGrid` and choose them in your new window. For example:

```
public class ColumnChooser
{        
    public bool IsShowIdStudent { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowFirstName { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowLastName { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowGroup { get; set; }
    public bool IsShowUniversity { get; set; }
}
```

And after that you can set `Visibility` for your column based on the class which is storing your boolean values like that:

```
YourDataGrid.Columns[IndexOftheColumn].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: There is 10 DataGrids that uses this Filter and they have different set of column names. I just don't want to duplicate this classes and other things. I think I've found the way to pass DataGrid with CommandParameter, but it's not working properly right now.